# How to call a method from an another method with ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have this little password generating program, I want the method `print_password` to call the `generate_password` method, but it just doesn't work

```
require 'digest'

class Challenge
  KEY = [
    '4', '5', '6', '7',
    '8', '9', 'A', 'B',
    'C', 'D', 'E', 'F',
    '0', '1', '2', '3'
  ]

  def initialize(email)
    @email = email # && raise
    puts 'This object was initialized!'
  end

  def print_password
    puts %(Password 1: {generate_password}) # Here I want to call generate_password method
  end

  private

  def generate_password
    @hash = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(@email)
    @id = @hash.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i).inject(:+)
    @prng = Random.new(@id)

    prepare_map
    apply_map
  end

  def prepare_map
    @map      = []
    id_string = @id.to_s
    id_size   = id_string.size

    map_string = id_string * (KEY.size.to_f / id_size).ceil

    0.upto(15) do |i|
      @map[i] = map_string[i].to_i
    end

    @map
  end
end

def apply_map
  calculated_key = KEY.shuffle(random: @prng).map.with_index do |char, i|
    (char.bytes[0] + @map[i]).chr
  end

  calculated_key.join
end

 me = Challenge.new('me@gmail.com') # Initialize new object
 me.print_password # Here I want to print the password
```

So here at the end, it initializes a new object and then where I use me.print_password it just prints out `Password 1: {generate_password}`

Don't know exactly what I am doing wrong here, thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: If you could make sure your question contains the *minimal* reproducible example, that would really help us zero in on the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a hash character before your curly brackets (same notation as for double quotes):

```rb
puts %(Password: #{generate_password})
puts "Password: #{generate_password}"
```

Comment: This was the correct answer! Thank you very much! :)